# AWS CLI usage from Google Cloud Shell

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

I installed AWS CLI on GCP Cloud shell as per [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) for Linux:

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

This works as expected but when returning after an overnight break I get the error:

```
-bash: aws: command not found
```

The AWS folder is still in my home directory:

```
ls ~/aws
dist  install  README.md  THIRD_PARTY_LICENSES
```

How do I maintain access without re-installing?

Update:

My understanding is the core VM is ephemeral for cloud shell but the home directory is saved between sessions.

Looks like I need to modify the installer to install in my home directory. This is the default installer script.

`sudo ./aws/install --bin-dir /usr/local/bin --install-dir /usr/local/aws-cli --update`

How do I modify this script to install in the correct directories in my home directory?

Comment: Which image did you use on GCP?

Comment: By default the installer installs the aws cli to `/usr/local/aws-cli` and then makes the symlinks to `/usr/local/bin`. If after installing the aws cli you cannot use `aws` binary then the `/usr/local/bin` must be not in PATH or installed binaries were purged from the `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: My understanding is the core VM is ephemeral for cloud shell but the home directory is saved between sessions.

Comment: I guess I need to modify the installer to install in my home directory.  This is the default installer script.  `sudo ./aws/install --bin-dir /usr/local/bin --install-dir /usr/local/aws-cli --update`